# DFT algorithm in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dft

In my university we are designing in MATLAB a algorithm to calculate the DFT of a signal $x(n)$.

Here is the algorithm:

```
x = [1 2 1 3]; 
N = length(x); 
nk = 0:N-1; 
for k = 0:N-1 
  for n = 0:N-1 
     X_products(n+1) = x(n+1)*exp(-j*2*pi*k*n/N);
  end
  Xk(k+1) = sum(X_products);
end
```

However I dont think it is correct.Shouldnt the 6th line be:

```
X_products(n) =X_products(n)+ x(n)*exp(-j*2*pi*k*n/N);
```

and the 8th line be:

```
Xk(k) = sum(X_products);
```

Comment: I strongly recommend taking an introductionary class into Matlab or do some basic tutorials, before trying to write an actual algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

First of all, that would give you an error at $n=0$ and $k=0$.

Also, you’d be doing a (non-working) cumulative sum at line 6 and then summing it all at line 8. That’s not the DFT. The implementation you posted is fine (except l.3 is obsolete).

Answer (score 0):

Read [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/discrete-fourier-transform.html) showing how to DFT with FFT and modify it accordingly to your needs.